# Check which flags are On/Off of an Integer Number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all Sorry for my English. Let say I have,

```
0 // 0
1 // 1
2 // 10
3 // 11
4 // 100
5 // 101
6 // 110
7......................
```

Now, I can say that 5 has two(3rd and 1st) ON flags. Similarly, 7 has three(1st, 2nd and 3rd) ON flags and so on.

Now, let say I have a input 2 and flag1, flag2, ..... flagn. I need to find pro-grammatically that only flag2 is ON.

Comment: and you want this in a combinatoin of c#, javascript and jquery? Could you add the correct tags, or explain what these language have to do with it?

Comment: Show us your code then. You have some piece of javascript hwere you have this number? binary?

Comment: @Nanne, I don't have any code. The example above will tell you what I need.

Comment: Your own personal code production site... well played :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, as you already can see at the binary representation. A 3 can either be 3 or 2+1. So use powers of two:

```
0 // 0000
1 // 0001
2 // 0010
4 // 0100
8 // 1000
```

Then when examining a value of `5 (0101)`, you'll see the bits for 1 and 4 are set, so you know which flags were enabled.

I don't know the exact JavaScript syntax, but something like this will do:

```
FLAG_1 = 1
FLAG_2 = 2
FLAG_3 = 4
FLAG_4 = 8
FLAG_5 = 16

var foo = FLAG_2 | FLAG_5; // Use binary OR (|) to add flags

if (foo & FLAG_5)
{
    // Do something that has to be done when FLAG_5 is set
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in javscript.

Comment: This is the solution provided many SO questions, but I have doubt, how to store more than 30 flags ? Because I can create flags till 30, using 1 << 30, after that which goes negative..

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with [JavaScript bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), the `&` operator in particular. If the input number is `2` then you can check which flags are set like so:

```
console.log(2 & 1); // 1 = 00000001b, result = 0
console.log(2 & 2); // 2 = 00000010b, result = 2, bingo!
console.log(2 & 4); // 4 = 00000100b, result = 0
console.log(2 & 8); // 8 = 00001000b, result = 0
```

The behavior of this operator is described as follows:

> Bitwise AND
>
> Returns a one in each bit position for which the
>   corresponding bits of both operands are ones.

## Edit

The above example can be written in a loop like so:

```
var input = 7;
for(var bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
    var mask = Math.pow(2, bit);
    console.log("bit #" + bit + " is", (input & mask) == mask ? "set" : "clear");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to find flags.

Comment: @user960567: see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a flag is on using & operator with the position of the flag (0-indexed)

```
if (num & (1 << flagPosition)) { /*flag is on */}
else { /*flag is off */}
```

You can check if only one flag is on using & with a number of this form 2^N - 1 (where N is maximum number of flags + 1)

```
var N = (1 << 31) - 1;
if (N & num == 1 << flagPosition)  {/* only flagPosition is ON*/}
else { /*flagPosition is OFF or there are other ON flags*/}
```

Comment: Thanks but I think @CodeCaster answer is more accurate and simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 6
arr = new Array();
while(num!=0){
   arr.push(num%2);
   num = parseInt(num/2);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Arr will have the bits 1 & 0 from which you can find the ON